# Find the probability of an A or B happening but not both

Tags: probability

My question, Find the probability that the next customer fills the tank completely, or uses unleaded, but not both.

I have the probability of those events, Probability of filling up completely is 0.4 and the probability of using unleaded fuel was 0.65

Could someone please help answer and find the probability of either of them happening but not both
Thanks

Comment: Do we know that these events are independent?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that (if they are independent phenomena):

$P = (0.4)(1-0.65)+(1-0.4)(0.65)=\cdots$

Comment: I don't think they are independent. your answer gives $0.53$ which seems quite strange since doing either $A$ or $B$ can't be less possible than doing just $A$

Comment: @Noxet It's $A$ **xor** $B$. It excludes the union.

Comment: @Noxet:  Probability possible cases:

$P_1=P_{AB}=0.4⋅0.65=0.26,P_2=P_{A\bar{B}}=0.4⋅0.35=0.14,P_3=P_{\bar{A}B}=0.6⋅0.65=0.39,P_4=P_{\bar{A}\bar{B}}=0.6⋅0.35=0.21,∑P_i=1.$

Seeking probability $P=P_2+P_3=0.53$, provided that the independent phenomena.

Comment: Ah yes of course, my mistake =)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can split your event of "either $A$ or $B$ but not both" into two disjoint events, on which you can use the fact that if $C\cap D=\emptyset$, then $P(C\cup D)=P(C)+P(D)$.